# How to append the first item of list to the end of all permutations of that list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

If I have a list of five items and I want to get every permutation of that list how would keep the first and last item the same?

As in, that list of five items would results in 120 permutations of a list where there then would be six items in that list but the first and last item would be the same. Below is what I have done so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from itertools import permutations
airportlist = ["airport1", "airport2", "airport3", "airport4", "airport5"]

permlist = permutations(airportlist, 5)
print(permlist)
print(list(permlist))

for i in list(permlist):

    newlist = (list(i))

    print(newlist)# getting e.g. ['airport1', 'airport5', 'airport2', 'airport4', 'airport3']

    print(list(i)[0]) # getting (to continue above example) airport1
    newerlist = (list(i).append((list(i)[0])))

    print(newerlist)#getting None but want ['airport1', 'airport5', 'airport2', 'airport4', 'airport3', 'airport1']
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am getting you right, you want to keep the first and the last airport the same as the original list, and generate the permutations of the elements in between. In that case, you could do something like below, wherein you generate the permutations for only the elements in the middle:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> airports = ["airport1", "airport2", "airport3", "airport4", "airport5"]
>>> [airports[:1] + list(x) + airports[-1:] for x in permutations(airports[1:-1])]
[['airport1', 'airport2', 'airport3', 'airport4', 'airport5'], ['airport1', 'airport2', 'airport4', 'airport3', 'airport5'], ['airport1', 'airport3', 'airport2', 'airport4', 'airport5'], ['airport1', 'airport3', 'airport4', 'airport2', 'airport5'], ['airport1', 'airport4', 'airport2', 'airport3', 'airport5'], ['airport1', 'airport4', 'airport3', 'airport2', 'airport5']]
```

---

***Edit***:

Re-reading your question, I think you may want to create the permutations, where the start and end airports are same, and the values in the middle get permuted, whic would be pretty simple:

```
>>> combos = [list(x) + [x[0]] for x in permutations(airports)]
>>> for x in combos: print x
['airport1', 'airport2', 'airport3', 'airport4', 'airport5', 'airport1']
['airport1', 'airport2', 'airport3', 'airport5', 'airport4', 'airport1']
... 
... 
['airport5', 'airport4', 'airport3', 'airport1', 'airport2', 'airport5']
['airport5', 'airport4', 'airport3', 'airport2', 'airport1', 'airport5']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That's great but not exactly want I'm looking for.

Comment: I would like e.g.  ['airport1', 'airport3', 'airport2', 'airport4', 'airport5'],['airport2', 'airport3', 'airport1', 'airport4', 'airport5']...#all 120 permutations] to become: ['airport1', 'airport3', 'airport2', 'airport4', 'airport5', 'airport1'], ['airport2', 'airport3', 'airport1', 'airport4', 'airport5', 'airport2'] i.e. still permutating all of the list but adding the first item to the end the list each time. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Just, well, append the first item of each list to each list.

```
from itertools import permutations
airportlist = ["airport1", "airport2", "airport3"]

perms = permutations (airportlist)
newperms = [list (x) + [x[0]] for x in perms]

for element in list (newperms):
    print element
```

The result is:

```
['airport1', 'airport2', 'airport3', 'airport1']
['airport1', 'airport3', 'airport2', 'airport1']
['airport2', 'airport1', 'airport3', 'airport2']
['airport2', 'airport3', 'airport1', 'airport2']
['airport3', 'airport1', 'airport2', 'airport3']
['airport3', 'airport2', 'airport1', 'airport3']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is:

```
[airportlist[:1] + list(i) + airportlist[:1] for i in permutations(airportlist[1:])]
```